# MVC Application With WebForms Application in subdirectory

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

This question has been asked before, and I understand it is possible. However I need a few points clarifying, which I beleive are unique to my particular situation, so that it warrants another question being created.

We are in the process of developing a ASP.NET MVC 4 application. As part of this application, within a subdirectory we wish to place a ASP.NET WebForms application. This WebForms application was not created in house, so we do not have the source code for the application, just the compiled binary files.

I am encountering an issue in that the MVC application uses Active Directory Authentication, and the WebForms application uses Forms based Authentication. I cannot for the life of me get the two applications working seamlessly together, even though the sub directory containing the WebForms application has its own web config specifying its own authentication settings.

I am also encountering an issue, where the WebForms application has its own Bin folder, ideally, I do not want to place references to the WebForms application in the Bin folder of my MVC application. However when I create a Bin folder within the sub directory, the WebForms application complains that it is unable to find a reference to a project which is not referenced in the WebForms application (it is however a reference to the MVC application).

Has anyone ever encountered a scenario such as this one? How did you mitigate the issues?

Comment: For authentication, which application acts as the gateway? Does the user land on the MVC and then goes to WebForms or the user is authenticated twice? Secondly, have you deployed both the applications in their own virtual applications or the web forms is placed in a normal sub-folder?

Comment: Hi Vijay, each application controls it own authentication method. As there is no shared authentication between the two. They are both configured as applications.